# BoxLayout from bottom to top (JavaSwing)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a few components in which I am adding elements using `BoxLayout`, but my problem is I need some of them to displayed bottom to top instead of top to bottom. How can I achieve that? Is there a way to do this with `BoxLayout` or is there a more suitable layout that adds elements first elements to the bottom of the container and then stacks them up?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have a few containers with BoxLayout to which I'm adding JLabels. Everything is fine just for some of these containers I want the adding to actually start from the bottom of the container, so it fills bottom-up.

Comment: Add the components in the reverse order! In order to constrain them to the 'bottom' of the available space, add the panel with box layout to a layout / constraint that will show it at the bottom (e.g. the `PAGE_END` of a `BorderLayout`).

Comment: The order doesn't matter for me, it is that the element has to be filled up from the bottom, so when I have 1 element it should be placed directly on the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a more suitable layout that adds elements first elements to the bottom of the container and then stacks them up?

The general rule is:

```
add(component);
```

adds the component to the end of the container.

```
add(component, 0);
```

adds the component to the beginning of the container.

The exact layout depends on the combination of panel and layout managers you are using.

For example you would need to add the panel using the vertical BoxLayout to the PAGE_END of the frame for all the components to be at the bottom.

Comment: My problem is not the order of the elements, so lets say I have an empty container, adding to 0 and to end will be the same thing but I need that element to be added at the bottom of the container. Adding a 2nd element should still keep the 2 elements at the bottom of the container - like a bottle of water - I need my elements to fill my container from bottom to top.

Comment: @Geri, And I already explained that. You have a panel using your BoxLayout and you keep adding the components add index 0. Then you add this panel to the JFrame (which uses a BorderLayout by default) using BorderLayout.PAGE_END as the constraint. Now the entire panel is displayed at the bottom of the frame and each object you add will be at the top of the panel.